# KLEE WARNING undefined function

Tags: llvm, libraries, llvm-gcc, klee

I've compiled `Wireshark` into `LLVM` then I proceeded to link against some libraries which I also compiled into `LLVM`.

The libraries I linked were `libwsutil`, `libz` and `libpcap`. However KLEE still gives me a warning for undefined function for `libpcap`.

I compiled libpcap by using these flags:

```
CC="llvm-gcc" CFLAGS="-flto -c" AR="llvm-ar" LD="llvm-ld"
```

These flags worked for the other libraries too.

What could be the cause?

```
KLEE: WARNING ONCE: function "capture_loop_dispatch" has inline asm
KLEE: WARNING ONCE: function "__user_main" has inline asm
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: __ctype_b_loc
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: __xstat64
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: bpf_image
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: cap_free
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: cap_init
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: cap_set_flag
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: cap_set_proc
...
...
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: lseek64
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_activate
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_breakloop
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_can_set_rfmon
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_close
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_compile
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_create
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_datalink
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_datalink_name_to_val
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_datalink_val_to_description
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_datalink_val_to_name
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_dispatch
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_findalldevs
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_free_datalinks
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_freealldevs
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_freecode
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_get_selectable_fd
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_geterr
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_lib_version
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_list_datalinks
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_lookupnet
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_open_live
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_set_buffer_size
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_set_datalink
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_set_promisc
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_set_rfmon
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_set_snaplen
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_set_timeout
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_setfilter
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_snapshot
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_stats
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: pcap_statustostr
KLEE: WARNING: undefined reference to function: prctl
```

Comment: Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit architecture? Perhaps the signatures of missing pcap functions use 64-bit integers, like missing lseek64 does.

Comment: I am using a 32-bit machine to compile everything.

Comment: This might be source of the problem. Try hinting it somehow to force it to use 32-bit variants (`-D ...` option?). You might need to look at the source code to see how to do it; searching for instructions like `#ifdef ...` might be a good start...

Comment: I've looked at the source code and I found `#define lseek64 lseek` so I assume there are a few line for compatibility purposes. Removing them should do the trick but does not appear to be the issue for `libpcap`.

Answer (score 3):

Read the "Getting Started" of KLEE at [Getting Started](http://klee.github.io/getting-started/)

> By default, KLEE works on closed programs (programs that don’t use any
> external code such as C library functions). However, if you want to
> use KLEE to run real programs you will want to enable the KLEE POSIX
> runtime, which is built on top of the uClibc C library.

So the KLEE can not use the C library function defaultly, if you use KLEE with the option `libc=uclibc`, the KLEE will link the external function into your IR code, and execute the IR code